# foreach loop multiple array value update using pdo

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

```
<?php
$roll  = $_POST['roll'];
$score = $_POST['a'];
$test  = $_SESSION['test'];
$class = $_SESSION['class'];
print_r($roll);
print_r($score);
global $pdo;
require('connect.php');
$stmt=$pdo->prepare("update atten set $test=? where roll=?");
foreach( $roll as $rollno)
{
    $stmt->bindparam(2,$rollno);
    foreach( $score as $key)
    {
        $stmt->bindparam(1,$score);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
if($stmt==false)
{
    die("error".print_r($stmt->errorinfo()));
}
?>
```

Here `$roll` is a array value and `$score` is also array value. here 
last value update for all roll no as example
`$roll=1,2,3,4` and `$score(10,20,30)` I don't know but here 30 value update for all roll no.
please help me.. thank you..

Comment: You're putting your `global $pdo;` outside of the scope of your DB connection. Yet, using that method is not advised. And where is your `session_start();` ? Plus, this is wrong `$stmt->bindparam(2,$rollno);`

Comment: can you explain as example of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you are saving every single score against all your rolls, so the last score will always be set to your roll.

The mistake is that you are using two foreach loops, but you only need one, you just need to match the rolls and scores to one another.

Iff you are absolutely certain the arrays are the same length and are indexed the same way (have the same keys - you can use the [array_values](https://www.php.net/array_values) PHP function to make sure) you can use a for loop instead

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($roll); $i++){
    $stmt->bindparam(1, $roll[$i]);
    $stmt->bindparam(2, $score[$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

The PHP function [array_combine](http://nz1.php.net/array_combine) might be useful here too as you can just do something like:

```
array_combine($roll, $score);
```

And then use a foreach loop as usual.

Edit: As requested, an array_combine example:

```
<?php
$roll  = $_POST['roll'];
$score = $_POST['a'];
$test  = $_SESSION['test'];
$class = $_SESSION['class'];
print_r($roll);
print_r($score);
global $pdo;
require('connect.php');
$stmt=$pdo->prepare("update atten set $test=? where roll=?");

if(count($roll) !== count($score))
    die('Arrays are not the same length!');

$rollsToScores = array_combine($roll, $score);

foreach($rollsToScores as $roll => $score){
    $result = $stmt->execute(array($score, $roll));
    if($result === false){
        die("error".print_r($stmt->errorinfo()));
        break;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: if here i user for loops no value update into data base

Comment: I'm a little confused what is going on here then. You should try putting some debugging in and var_dump what exactly you are binding and that will help you figure out what is going on.

Comment: can you explain here array_combine()example

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `$array` in inner loop bind param `$stmt->bindparam(1,$score);`.

I think

```
$stmt->bindparam(1,$score);
```

Should be :-

```
$stmt->bindparam(1,$key);
```

**Modified Block of Code :-**

```
foreach( $roll as $rollno)
{
    $stmt->bindparam(2,$rollno);
    foreach( $score as $key)
    {
    $stmt->bindparam(1,$key);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```